# Make the previous 360 and following 360 values NA if the statement is true

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, time, posixct

I have a dataframe of values  (3 years in 10 minutes steps) and I want that if the barrier is higher than 900 that x gets NA for that time and that the previous 360 and following 360 values also get NA. x and barrier contain NAs.

My dataframe consist out of: 
[image]

- Time 
  df$Time<- as.POSIXct(df$Time,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",tz="GMT") [10 minute steps]
- x 
  my value what I want to be sorted out by the barrier
- barrier
  if the barrier gets over 900 my x value should get NA 
  That works with df$x <- ifelse(df$barrier > 900, NA, df$x) here you can see.
  [image]

but I want that also the previous 6hours = 360 values should get NA as well as the following 6hours =360 values of x.

You can see on the picture that if the barrier (pink line) is over 900 the previous and following values are also affected (jumps), hence I want that the x values before and after get also NA . 
[image]

My problem is I do not know how I can remove the previous and following values of x

Comment: Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions and then provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), including sample data. We don't know anything about your data, which makes the code snippet you give completely useless. Always provide (1) sample data, (2) the code you've tried, and (3) the expected output based on your sample data. It's also not clear what you're actually asking. Did the command work? If not, why not. Were there errors? We need details!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find more elegant way but this works:

```
indeks <- df$barrier > 900
for(i in 1:360){
  if(indeks[i]==T){
    df$x[1:(i+360)] <- NA
  }
}
for(i in (360+1):(length(indeks)-361)){
  if(indeks[i]==T){
    df$x[(i-360):(i+360)] <- NA
  }
}
for(i in (length(indeks)-360):length(indeks)){
  if(indeks[i]==T){
    df$x[(i-360):lentgh(index)] <- NA
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesnt workt:     Error in if (indeks[i] == T) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: maybe due to NAs?

Comment: Removing NA in barrier made it work. Thank you a lot for your simple and working solution!

Comment: Yes, df$barrier should be NA free. @Nad